# Меню в мобильной версии, скролл по странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброй ночи!

Как сделать чтобы при пролистывании меню вниз, когда меню закончилось, страница дальше не листалась?

Сайт: http://victory-factory.ru/dd/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Например, добавлять при открытии меню к body класс, в котором будет соять свойство overflow: hidden. А при закрытии меню, убирать этот класс.

Answer (score 0):

В тот момент, когда меню открывается, присваивайте для `body` свойство `overflow: hidden;`, тогда ничего скроллиться не будет.